continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to Sorgenfrey line
My goal is to describe the continuous functions from the real line with the usual topology to the Sorgenfrey line.
My guess is that only constant functions are continuous.
Suppose $f$ is continuous and not constant let $a<b$ with WLOG, $f(a)>f(b)$.
Let $S=\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid f(x) \geq f(a)\}$.
Then $S \neq \emptyset \ (a \in S)$ and as $X=S \ \cap\  ]-\infty, b]$ is not empty and bounded above, there is $s=\sup(X)$.
We also have that for $\epsilon=\frac{|f(a)-f(b)|}{2}$, there exists $\delta>0$ s.t. :
$$f(B(b, \delta)) \subset \ [f(b), f(b) +\epsilon[$$
But now,  $s\neq b$ and that there exists points $p$ arbitrarily close to $s$ (from above) with $f(p)<f(a)\leq f(s)$ so $f$ is not continuous at $x=s$.
If $f(a)>f(b)$, then we could apply the same procedure to $-f$.
Is this valid?

Hint: the Sorgenfrey line is totally disconnected.
